# merge columns of a data frame to maintain only equal values in r

Tags: r, function, vector, merge

I have four vectors where the presence of an event is described as binomial (0 = absent, 1 = present).

I would like to combine these four vectors into one maintaing only the events (1) that are common in the four columns and assigning 0 to the rest.

Example:

```r
x <- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)
y <- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0)
z <- c(0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0)
```

In this case, the result I need by combining these 3 vectors would be:

```
r = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

I would like to know if there is any function that will do this quickly, couldn't find anything that useful until now.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, we can keep the `vector`s in a `list` and `Reduce` it to a single logical vector with `&`, convert to binary by coercing with `+` (or use `as.integer`)

```
+(Reduce(`&`, list(x, y, z)))
#[1] 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

If it is a `data.frame`

```
df1 <- list(x, y, z)
+(Reduce(`&`, df1))
```

Or if the values are different

```
i1 <- Reduce(`&`, list(x, y, z))
ifelse(i1, x, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they're in a dataframe...

```
df <- tibble(x = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0), #Creating the dataframe
             y = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0), 
             z = c(0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0)) %>%
      mutate(r = if_else(x == y  & y == z & z == x, #Creating the variable r. If all equal...
                         1, #1, 
                         0)) #else, 0
df$r
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

P.s. `%>%` is a pipe, if you're new to R